# no improvements on the following PLINQ code

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, plinq

I do not see any improvements in processing speed using the following code:

```
IEnumerable<Quote> sortedQuotes = (from x in unsortedQuotes.AsParallel()
                                           orderby (x.DateTimeTicks)
                                           select x);
```

over the sequential version:

```
IEnumerable<Quote> sortedQuotes = (from x in unsortedQuotes
                                           orderby (x.DateTimeTicks)
                                           select x);
```

Am I missing something here? I varied the number of items in the source collections from thousands to several tens of millions and no size showed the Parallel version coming out ahead.

Any tips appreciated. By the way if anyone knows of a faster way to sort more efficiently (given my indicated item variable type (containing a long DateTimeTicks by which the items are sorted in the collection) that would also be appreciate.

Edit: "sorting efficiently" -> As fast as possible.

Thanks

Comment: have you measured performance without orderby clause

Comment: Without orderby, how would I get a sorted collection returned?

Comment: @Freddy: just because something can be parallelised doesn't mean it's a good candidate to be parallelised .

Comment: I don't think LINQ has  a parallel sort (orderby). Edit: seems like it does.

Comment: @Mitch, disagree strongly here, some sort algos lend themselves perfectly for parallelization (divide and conquer,...). But I guess Henk is right, its not built in, I guess the sort function does not recognize the AsParallel and thus does not switch over to a more optimized sorting algorithm.

Comment: @Freedy: given that I was once a reseacher designing parallel algorithms, I have a reasonable knowledge of what algorithms parallelise well. Parallel Sorting, even done well, requires many synchronisation steps to put the sorted pieces back together. While it is possible, it doesn't always give you the magnitude of speedup you might hope for.

Comment: @Mitch, sorry but I still do not agree at all. First, I am not asking for magnitudes here, but a speedup should be measurable. Secondly, it has been shown in many research papers (latest tests I have seen were in-detail tests at Dr.Dobbs, happy to send you the links but your conclusion that there is not much to be expected going parallel is simply incorrect) that sorting algorithms benefit from parallelization, especially divide and conquer algos. The point of my post was to inquire whether any speedup is to be expected here in C#, using Linq's AsParallel() on top of OrderBy().

Comment: You are putting words into my mouth. I did NOT say that sorting algorithms do NOT benefit from parallelization; I said they may not always give you the speedup you expect.

Comment: @Mitch, I do not like to split hairs, so my apologies if I paraphrased you incorrectly but if I may ask from which part of my post did you get how much speedup I expect? Several in-depth tests (albeit implemented in C++) have shown simple int or long value sorting can be sped up through parallelization. In that I simply disagree with your assertion. I guess I just am not sure what the take-away from your very generalized comment was. What did you actually try to say other than that sometimes something may not turn out as expected? (meant with all due respect!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163329.aspx),

> If you have a sort in your query, stop-and-go will be used instead because pipelining the output of a sort is wasteful. A sort exhibits extremely high latency [...], and so PLINQ prefers to devote all processing power to completing the sort as quickly as possible.

Your query *only* contains a Sort, the select doesn't count. So the PLINQ engine will execute it as sequential.

You can only expect some improvement when the sorting is a part of a larger query.

Comment: thanks for the link, performance wise it looked very much like it, thanks for the reasoning behind it.